# application configuration as a docker image

Tags: docker

I'm trying to separate my application configuration file out from the application itself so that I can have a single docker image for application code and multiple images for storing different configurations.

I understand that you can use `--volume-from` to attach a data only container to the application container. But what I'd like to achieve is to have an **image** with all the configuration files and the application container can attach to a volume container from that image. I'm not sure if this is possible?

As far as I can see, there seems to be no way of running a data only container from a image. Data only container are normally generated with `docker create -v`. Hence this question.

Comment: Suppose you could get it running, how would your configuration container get distributed? You should look at something like [etcd](https://github.com/coreos/etcd) or [consul](https://www.consul.io/) to keep track of configurations.

Comment: Yes. Ultimately I'll go to consul but right now I just want something quick and dirty.

Comment: Could you mount the config file from the file system as a volume and skip the data container step?

Comment: Yes. But I'd like my configuration to be versioned, and image achieves that nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can run data only container from a custom image  having your config files.
for e.g.

```
docker create -v /volumeexposedinyourimage --name datacontainer yourimagename /bin/true
```

yourimagename - is the name of your custom image (which has your config files)
and volumeexposedinyourimage is the volume exposing your config files.

docker-compose example

```
version: '2'

services:
  datacontainer :
    image: yourimagename
    volumes: 
      - /volumeexposedinyourimage 
   command: ["/bin/true"]
  appcontainer:
    image: appimage
    volumes_from:
      - datacontainer
```

or you could mount host directory containing config files as volume 
e.g.

```
 docker run -d -P --name appcontainer -v /host/config:/path appimage
```

place your config files on /host/config on the host and in your appcontainer , you could refer to your config files using /path

Comment: How can this be combined with `docker-compose` file?

Comment: I have updated my answer to include docker-compos example

Comment: this requires a container running before `compse up`. I'd like it to be an image.